# Nativescript - Publish to IOS

Tags: app-store, nativescript, sidekick

So as everyone knows, publish to the appstore is a nightmare, at this precise moment i´m trying to publish my app but i keep getting erros regardless of using nativescript sidekick or using aplication loader, also i have done EVERY step that is said [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gKuR2UCOnM)... so:

**When using nativescript sidekick:**

1. I hit the publish button, select my certificate and provisioning
   profile.
2. Insert my appstore credentials
3. The error is: Errors is: The request can't receive any response
4. i Went [here](https://github.com/NativeScript/sidekick-feedback/issues/321) but the problem persists!.

**When uploading the ipa file in application loader:**

The error simply says(always!!!) that my provisioning profile is not for that bundle etc etc.

What can i do here? what is the problem?

Thanks for your time, regards

Comment: You could try and use a th3 party like AppCenter, and maybe have some more luck with It. https://appcenter.ms

Comment: Ok ... i never used it...but do you know any solution with sidekick or aplication loader?

Comment: I have no idea what is a sidekick. Application loader will need your configuration to be correct, it is very hard to know what is wrong from your short description. This is the reason I advise you to use a 3td party that does for you most of the heavy lifting

Comment: Did you try building it from [command line](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/testing/build-ios)?

Comment: Hey Manoj...no...i did not because i don´t know how to do it...but i´m starting to think that i have problems that could be related...for example whenever i try to start sidekick, i´m ALWAYS getting and error: [19-03-15 17:07:01.924] Downloading updates... and then: [19-03-15 17:07:01.951] Could not create temporary directory: Permission denied, Error: Could not create temporary directory: Permission denied

Comment: Hey Manoj could you give me an example on how to create a release .ipa file by comand line?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on the official [{NS} website](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/publishing-ios-apps) to create your ipa file try running:

```
tns build ios --release --forDevice
```

This will create an ipa file in this directory: `/platforms/ios/build/device`
Then try running this command to publish the App:

```
tns publish ios your-apple-id your-password --ipa path/to/ipa
```